# Psql could not connect to the server after moving the data directory on raspberry pi b+ stretch lite

Tags: postgresql, raspberry-pi

I mounted an external ntfs hdd to my raspberry pi. I installed postgresql 9.6 and ran the commands:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

Everything worked as expected. I then stopped the postgres service and ran the below command to copy the data directory to my external hdd:

```
sudo rsync -av /var/lib/postgresql /mnt/usbhdd
```

Next I edited the conf file and changed the data directory location:

```
sudo nano /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
data_directory = '/mnt/usbhdd/postgresql/9.6/main'
```

Then I restarted the postgres service but now when I run these commands:

```
sudo su postgres
psql
```

I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Could it be caused by the permissions on my nfts usb hdd?

Comment: If you have a good path to your data_directory that I think you checked at least twice. I think there can be a two problems. First is permission of postgres user for mounted hdd and the second some sort of problems with data_directory permissions for postgres user. You used -av flag so there should be the same rights but can you send a permission for a postgres user for hdd and data_directory?

Comment: You can check permission using ls -l. Let us know back with more information about your permissions setting.

Comment: @Bulva the permissions are as follows:
'drwxrwxrwx 1 pi pi 360 Jan 26 17:35 postgresql'

Comment: @Bulva The rest of the files have the same permissions. It looks like they all have read write execute?

Something maybe noteworthy is that the files have a green background with blue text when logged in with the pi user and they have a black background with white text when logged in with postgres as I know the colours are related to permissions.

Comment: Is this debian distro? Because on debian distros must be owner of folder postgres user in group postgres

Comment: You can try set owner for postgres user. Try this: sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /mnt/usbhdd/postgresql/9.6/
 and then sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /mnt/usbhdd/postgresql/9.6/

Comment: @Bulva this is raspbian stretch lite and the root account 'pi' is the owner, should postgres be the owner?

Comment: Try set the owner postgres with commands I sent and if it will not work after service restart we will see the logs :-)

Comment: @Bulva this did not work in changing the owner to postgres, but after more googling it seems like permissions don't work the same way with external hdds with the nfts format and you cannot change it with chmod.

However it looks like I can remount it with the correct permissions or I could format and change my partition from nfts. Would doing this and changing the owner to postgres fix the issue?

Comment: You can check Postgres logs. It should be in var/log/postgresql. Maybe there will be info about permissions. You are right with chmod on NTFS. I didn't know this. Then you will have to probably remount HDD. But first check the logs. Maybe there will be other problem, just for sure

Comment: what does `findmnt /mnt/usbhdd` say?  what does `su postgres -c ls /mnt/usbhdd/postgresql/9.6` say?

Comment: `Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket ...?` These are two questions. (answer them!) There are two possibilities: 1) the server failed to start 2) the server did start, but could not be found by the psql client.